# How do I check to make sure the customer has done a task before they visit any page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using the Membership provider on a MVC Razor website.

After the customer creates an account and then logs in, I need to make sure they add a system account(s) to their login otherwise the following pages will have issues.

Here is what my page looks like:

[image]

As you can see, they can click on any of the tabs at the top and circumvent this screen.

What is the best way to handle this?

Should I disable the tabs? If so, where would I disable them? Or should I do a check on each page and redirect them back to this page?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RedirectToAction()` if they have not created one e.g.

```
public ActionResult OrderGas(){

    // do check here to see if they have system account
    if (!hasSystemAccount()){

        // this will re-display the add another account page each time
        return RedirectToAction("AddAnotherAccountAction");
    }

    //other wise continue;
    return view("OrderGas");

}
```

Alternatively you can use javascript to hide the buttons depending on a model

```
public ActionResult OrderGas(){

    // do check here to see if they have system account
    Boolean hasAccount = this.hasSystemAccount();

    // apply to the model
    model.hasSystemAccount = hasAccount;


    return view("OrderGas", model);

}
```

Then your jquery can check this value and hide the links accordingly

```
if($('#hasSystemAccount').val().toLower() = "false"){

    $('.myLinkClass').hide();
}
```

Comment: yup, that's what I was thinking but didnt know if there is a better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should check whether that information has been entered before loading any other page.  (probably in an action filter)

If you just disable the links, malicious users can navigate directly to the URLs.

Comment: The tabs are protected by [Authorize] so it directs them to the login if they try to directly load them.

Comment: How do I disable them when they are in the _Layout.cshtml view and there isn't a action filter associated with them?

Comment: Why not use an additional ROLE that indicates a customer has added the 'system account' information, such as __CustomerWithSystemAccountInfo__.  Then you can protect the controller actions with `[Authorize(Roles = "CustomerWithSystemAccountInfo")]`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an additional Membership ROLE which indicates a customer has added the 'system account' information, such as *CustomerWithSystemAccountInfo*.

Then you can protect the controller actions with `[Authorize(Roles = "CustomerWithSystemAccountInfo")]`

As far as hiding or disabling the menu options in _layout based on ROLE the following article presents a way of doing it that I quite like:

http://techbrij.com/981/role-based-menu-asp-net-mvc